# What does "dot slash dot" (./.) mean in a Nix expression?

Tags: nix

Wherever I see [`flake-compat`](https://github.com/edolstra/flake-compat) used, it is a variation of

```hs
(import (fetchTarball https://github.com/edolstra/flake-compat/archive/master.tar.gz) {
  src = ./.;
}).shellNix
```

It is obviously a path that refers to the current directory which can be proven with a simple test:

```
[~/testdir]$ ll .
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 toraritte users  4096 Jul 21 21:56 ./
drwx------ 7 toraritte users 20480 Jul 15 23:13 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 toraritte users     0 Jul 21 21:56 lofa

[~/testdir]$ ll ./.
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 toraritte users  4096 Jul 21 21:56 ./
drwx------ 7 toraritte users 20480 Jul 15 23:13 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 toraritte users     0 Jul 21 21:56 lofa
```

So why not simply use `.`?

Answer (score 3):

From [5.2.1 Values section of the Nix manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/expressions/language-values.html) (emphasis mine):

> Paths, e.g., `/bin/sh` or `./builder.sh`. **A path must contain at least one
> slash to be recognised as such.**
>
> For instance, `builder.sh` is not a
> path: it's parsed as an expression that selects the attribute `sh` from
> the variable `builder`. If the file name is relative, i.e., if it does
> not begin with a slash, it is made absolute at parse time relative to
> the directory of the Nix expression that contained it. For instance,
> if a Nix expression in `/foo/bar/bla.nix` refers to `../xyzzy/fnord.nix`,
> the absolute path is `/foo/xyzzy/fnord.nix`.